# Getting POST parameters on both, form and json format

Tags: python, api, post, flask, http-post

My webservice should receive calls in these two formats: **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** and **content-type application/json**.

The code below works correctly for the forms. However, it doesn't work for the json ones. Apparently I need to use `request.args.get` for it.

Is there a way to modify the code so that the same method can receive calls in these two formats?

```
@app.route("/api/<projectTitle>/<path:urlSuffix>", methods=['POST'])
def projectTitlePage(projectTitle, urlSuffix):

    apiKey = request.form.get('apikey')
    userId = databaseFunctions.getApiKeyUserId(apiKey)
    userInfo = databaseFunctions.getUserInfo(userId)
    projectId = databaseFunctions.getTitleProjectId(projectTitle)
    projectInfo = databaseFunctions.getProjectInfo(projectId)
    databaseFunctions.addUserHit(userId, projectId)
    databaseFunctions.addProjectHit(userId)

    print request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
    try:
        r = requests.post(projectInfo['secretUrl'], data=request.form.to_dict(flat=False))
    except Exception, e:
        return '/error=Error'

    return r.text
```

Comment: can you add your includes and how your request object is assigned?

Comment: Have you tried branching the request processing based on the HTTP CONTENT-TYPE header?

Comment: Hi @RPhillipCastagna. Can you please expand your comment in an answer? I think that might work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to get the JSON using [`Request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.get_json); an exception is raised if that fails, after which you can fall back to using `request.form`:

```
from flask import request
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest

try:
    data = request.get_json()
    apiKey = data['apikey']
except (TypeError, BadRequest, KeyError):
    apiKey = request.form['apikey']
```

If the mimetype is not `application/json`, `request.get_json()` returns `None`; trying to use `data['apikey']` then results in a `TypeError`. The mimetype being correct but the JSON data being invalid gives you a `BadRequest`, and all other invalid return values either result in a `KeyError` (no such key) or a `TypeError` (object doesn't support indexing by name).

The other option would be to test the [`request.mimetype` attribute](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.CommonRequestDescriptorsMixin.mimetype):

```
if request.mimetype == 'application/json':
    data = request.get_json()
    apiKey = data['apiKey']
else:
    apiKey = request.form['apikey']
```

Either way, if there is no valid JSON data or form data was posted but there is no `apikey` entry or an unrelated mimetype was posted, a `BadRequest` exception will be raised and a 400 response is returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not incredibly familiar with Flask in particular, but based on their documentation you should be able to do something like

```
content = request.headers['CONTENT-TYPE']

if content[:16] == 'application/json':
   # Process json
else:
   # Process as form-encoded
```

Comment: This won't work if a parameter was added to the request; `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` is a perfectly valid header to send.

Comment: Instead, use the Werkzeug `Request` object API; the `mimetype` attribute contains the `Content-Type` contents without any MIME parameters.

Comment: Well there ya go! Like I said, not terribly familiar with Flask in particular

Answer (score 0):

My approach to fetch the `json` and `form-data` regardless of the header was like

```py
data = request.get_json() or request.form
key = data.get('key')
```